# Файл main_activity не видит элементы интерфейса

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть текстовый блок с id `resultText`, когда я  пытаюсь  к  нему обратиться  в файле main_activity, то его не видно и  так  со  всеми элементами.  Пожалуйста подскажите,  что я  делаю  не  так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `build.grable` приложения проверьте:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

С недавних пор `deprecated`, рекомендуют пользоваться `View Binding`.